# Change aspect of highcharts sankey chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to build a sankey chart from highcharts.js to look like the one in the example image, basically what I try to do is change the shape and position of some flows and nodes in the chart.
Help will be apreciated since I cant find any solucion in the internet.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {...});
```

[codepen sankey code](https://codepen.io/marcio-oliveira/pen/BaJGbmb)

[sankey exemple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y242P.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Relating to sankey this series have some limitations, to adjust you can use [nodeWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodeWidth), [nodePadding](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodePadding) and [minLinkWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.minLinkWidth).

*The nodes are generated so that the total weight going in or out of a node is visualized. Nodes are instances of Point and are available from the series.nodes array. The width of the nodes can be set with the nodeWidth option, and padding between them with nodePadding.*

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/sankey-diagram#nodes

Comment: Yes I know, about the padding and width, but I can’t achieve the desired shape of the flow (curve) with the padding or width, the example image was made with d3.js so I was thinking that we can achieve the same result in highcharts.

Comment: All that's left is for you to match that look but it won't be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly hack that can do what you need. I had no time to properly finish it, but it works.

What you can do now, is to set the node incoming and outgoing options and play with vertical-horizontal-offset.

```js
nodes=[
{id:'import'    ,column:1, offsetVertical:-100 ,offsetHorizontal:-20},
{id:'production',column:0, offsetVertical:22 ,offsetHorizontal:0},
{id:'total'     ,column:2, offsetVertical:0 ,offsetHorizontal:0},
{id:'loss'      ,column:3, offsetVertical:50 ,offsetHorizontal:0},
{id:'final'     ,column:5, offsetVertical:-10 ,offsetHorizontal:0},
{id:'export'    ,column:4, offsetVertical:50 ,offsetHorizontal:0},

]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: (9/16 * 90 )+ "%"
  },
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [{
      from: 'import',
      to: 'total',
      weight: 80,
      incoming: true
    }, {
      from: 'production',
      to: 'total',
      weight: 20,
    }, {
      from: 'total',
      to: 'final',
      weight: 56,
    }, {
      from: 'total',
      to: 'export',
      weight: 17,
      outgoing: true
    }, {
      from: 'total',
      to: 'loss',
      weight: 27,
      outgoing: true
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      nodeFormat: '{point.name}: {point.sum}%',
      padding: 20,
      style: {
        fontSize: '0.8em'
      }
    },
    nodes: nodes,
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Energy',
    linkOpacity: 1,
  }]

});
```

Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikero/vuwgy0hm/)

I changed sankey.js directly and also used the proto translate option.
Main changes:

- Redraw the SVG path for all, except the circular link
- Replace the SVG path fill with the stroke-width
- Top justify nodes instead of center